# 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

my code is

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    ///   labels - names of Cities   ///


    UILabel *lblCity = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 00, 200, 22)];
    lblCity.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lblCity.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //lblCity.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lblDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 00, 200, 22)]; 
    lblDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *lblSchool = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 00, 400, 22)];
    lblSchool.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lblSchool.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //lblSchool.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    ///    Labels for description of city events    ///


    UILabel *lblEvent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 00, 200, 30)];
    lblEvent.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *lblEventAtDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 00, 200, 30)];
    lblEventAtDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblEventAtDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *lblEventAtSchool = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 00, 400, 30)];
    lblEventAtSchool.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    lblEventAtSchool.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    if(RequestType == 2)
    {

        UIImageView *imgEventLabel = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 00, 480, 22)];

        UIView *viewDescription = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 00, 480, 35)];


        if(indexPath.row == 0)

        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell11";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

                lblCity.text = @"City" ;
            //  [cell addSubview:lblCity];

                lblDate.text = @"Date" ;
            //  [cell addSubview:lblDate];

                lblSchool.text = @"School" ;
            //  [cell addSubview:lblSchool];

                imgEventLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city_date_place.png"];
            //  [cell addSubview:imgEventLabel];



                [imgEventLabel addSubview:lblCity];
                [imgEventLabel addSubview:lblDate];
                [imgEventLabel addSubview:lblSchool];

                [cell.contentView addSubview:imgEventLabel];

            }

            return cell;
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 1)

        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell12";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 999;


                lblEvent.text = @"Event in City";
                lblEventAtDate.text = @"Event on Date";
                lblEventAtSchool.text = @"Event at School";

                [viewDescription addSubview:lblEvent];
                [viewDescription addSubview:lblEventAtDate];
                [viewDescription addSubview:lblEventAtSchool];

                [cell.contentView addSubview:viewDescription];

            }

            return cell;


    }


    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

I don't know where is fault, Please Help.

Comment: You don't have to return the cell again after you have returned it inside your condition.

Comment: what error your getting..please provide gdb statments if it is crashing..

Comment: nitish no prob even return two times bec in the first return statement the method execution completed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your first call of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` You didn't check for nil and create a new one if there are no available cells in the reuse queue.

In other words, if there are no cells in the reuse queue, your request type is not equal to 2, and row is not equal to 0 or 1, your cell will not be created. This causes an exception you see in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

you don't need to write that on start as you create the cell according to conditions .

At the end just return nil. Because I think there must be some condition true when you execute your code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not have enough points to comment on your question. Have you tried using Custom Cells? Custom Cell is like a modification of the current TableViewCells. You can do almost anything you want to that the TableViewCells do not provide. From what I see, you want 3 Labels and 1 Image. A normal TableViewCell will not give you that ability to have 3 Labels. Unless you create it yourself. Below is a link for you to do so. I hope this is what you have in mind.

[iPhone Custom Cell Tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)